# How to use the cordova HTTP plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, http, cordova-plugins, http-get

I want to get the source code of a website so I found [a plugin](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP) that makes HTTP requests but I'm not sure how to use it for this case

I am using this code but it's doing nothing:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    window.cordovaHTTP.get("http://www.lycee-tripoli.edu.lb/",
    {},
    {},
    function(response) {
        alert(response.status);
    },
    function(response) {
        alert(response.error);
    });
}, false);
```

This code should alert the response, but it's doing nothing at all: no error messages, no response, nothing: it's just a blank page! I copied this from the [README.md file](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP#get). I want to use pure JS and not Angular. Am I doing something wrong? If anyone could help me debug this, it would be greatly appreciated. I am using [this APK](https://ufile.io/7fvj1).

I need help!

Comment: let me know what is response your getting

Comment: The problem is that's I'm getting a white, blank screen

Comment: function(response) {
        console.log(response.status); 
    },                    In this can u tell me what response is comming

Comment: Yeah, I'm using `alert` instead but it should do the same thing. I think you're not understanding what I mean. I'm getting *no* response. @ShanmugapriyaD

Comment: In error also u r not getting anything is it ?

Comment: I'm getting *nothing*. Would you like the APK?